# Image map disables <A> tag on image

Tags: javascript, html, css, dictionary, image

I've got some thumbnails and I want each to be a different link. The following code usually works fine:

```
<a href=#><img src=# /></a>
```

However, I made each thumbnail an image map (so the thumbnail image changes as you mouse over). Now, no matter where I put the `<a>` tag, the image refuses to be a link. Even using JavaScript on the div that encloses the image.
It's worth noting that the image has a title (in a `<span>` tag) below it. This does function fine as a link.

How can I get this image to be both a link and a map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I see...

Well, image map is an exclusive alternative to `<a>` tag.

If you want to use this kind of behaviour, I'll suggest creating 3 divs over the image each with separate onMouseOver handler and leave `<a>` tag around the `<img>` element to get onClick behaviour.

As second alternative you can extend divs not only with onMouseOver event handler but also with onClick event handler and process clicking within single function.

Comment: "Well, image map is an exclusive alternative to tag." So, there's no way to do this with a map?

Comment: Thanks, based on your advice, I made three div 'columns' with JS triggers, and it's working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you use image maps? There is no need to use image maps to get this kind of behaviour.

Comment: Allow me to clarify: I use the map to define three regions across the image. As you move your mouse across the image, it passes through each 'column'. Each column triggers a JS function to change that image. So, as you move your mouse across the image, it changes three times. A bit like iPhoto, if you've seen that. I'm building a photography websiste, and these thumbnails will represent a gallery. As people move over the thumbnail, it changes to give them a preview of what else is in that gallery.